# Can postgres make use of both GIN and BTREE indexes in a single query?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

Let's say I have GIN index on column A that allows me to filter table fast on that column by appropriate WHERE condition which would be slow without that index. However I would like also to order filtered rows by using ORDER BY statement on, let's say column B. Ordering without index is slow, so I use BTREE index on column B. The problem is that pg don't want to use both indexes - if both WHERE cond on column A and ORDER BY B are present in query, pg uses only GIN index. When I remove WHERE cond from query, then it uses BTREE index on col B.

What I can do to force pg to use both indexes, one to filter rows and second one to order them?

Comment: How many rows will the query return? If an index (GIN or whatever) helps Postgres to efficently select 1000 rows among millions, then the sorting should not be a problem, with or without an index.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the output of `explain (analyze, verbose)` for your queries. I think you are overestimating the cost of sorting. For a few thousand rows it's most probably faster to sort them in memory than to read the sort key from an index and then do a lookup based on that index.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your title question, `PostgreSQL` can make use of multiple indexes for a "bitmap" scan, but only with Boolean logic.  It can't use one to order and the other to filter within the same table scan.  It is an interesting idea, though.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of :(. So it means that when my WHERE filter uses GIN index, but still returning significant number of rows that I want to order/limit, then it always will be slow since it can't use another index (BTREE) to sort them right? Is there any workaround?

Comment: I can't think of other options (other than to go implement the feature--it is an open source database, after all, but it would not be trivial to implement this).  But seeing the query and the `explain (analyze, buffers)` output might lead to some inspiration.  Is there a `LIMIT` ?  Why is the sorting so slow?

Comment: For example after WHERE filter query returns 500k rows, and then I am sorting on TEXT field for example. Sorting 500k rows is slow without index. The only option I can imagine is to use `WITH (SELECT ... WHERE ...) SELECT ... ORDER BY ... LIMIT ...`, then there will be two separate queries and I hope PG will use separate index for each of them - I haven't tried it though.